# Feeding emails from imap folder into sieve script

Tags: imap, dovecot

I have IMAP folders on a dovecot server containing a high number of emails (>10.000). I want to apply an existing sieve script to the mails in these folders. I know I can feed the mails from the Maildir storage into dovecot's lmtp and remove the file afterwards but I want to preserve the mail status as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't tried it myself, it sounds like you're looking for the "[IMAPSieve](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve/Plugins/IMAPSieve)" extension for Sieve. It allows you to assign a Sieve script based on moving an email to a particular folder. I would think you could set up a new folder with a script that takes whatever action you want upon moving the mail into it. And then if needed, you could move the mail back out of the folder to its original folder after the processing you're looking for is done.

There's an example on the Dovecot site that explains [hooking into a spam filter](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/AntispamWithSieve), such that moving a message into a spam folder runs a spam training command on it. I'd start adapting what you are looking to do from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating new folder, move all messages to that folder and then move them back to the previous place where the sieve filter is defined - sieve rules should then be applied.

Comment: That will not work as sieve is used by the local mail delivery agent (in my case dovecot lmda) and not the IMAP server.